# Variable in select query

Tags: php, variables

Can someone tell me what is wrong here:

```
if (isset($_GET['preis']) AND $_GET['preis']==="0-100-euro"){
    $preis = "WHERE preis >= 0 and preis <= 100";
}
if (isset($_GET['preis']) AND $_GET['preis']==="100-200-euro"){
    $preis = "WHERE preis >= 100 and preis <= 200";
}
if (isset($_GET['preis']) AND $_GET['preis']==="200-300-euro"){
    $preis = "WHERE preis >= 200 and preis <= 300";
}
?>


$abfrage = "SELECT * FROM outfits $preis LIMIT $start, $eintraege_pro_seite";
$ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage);
```

$preis is not working in the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following code

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['preis']) && $_GET['preis']==="0-100-euro")
{
    $preis = "WHERE preis >= 0 and preis <= 100";
}
elseif (isset($_GET['preis']) && $_GET['preis']==="100-200-euro")
{
     $preis = "WHERE preis >= 100 and preis <= 200";
}
elseif (isset($_GET['preis']) && $_GET['preis']==="200-300-euro")
{
     $preis = "WHERE preis >= 200 and preis <= 300";
}
else
{
     $preis = "WHERE preis >= 200 and preis <= 300";
}


$abfrage = "SELECT * FROM outfits $preis LIMIT $start, $eintraege_pro_seite";  
$ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage);
?>
```

Always try to use elseif or a case for this. Using the else at the end means there will be a WHERE statement if the previous rules are not matched. It could potentially just be something as simple as this, that the conditions are not met and therefore $abfrage does not exist. This will prove this.

Comment: But you should use a switch not an ifelse jungle.

Comment: elseif and && instead AND is working. Bt not with rewrite rules: RewriteRule ^preis-([^-]*)/$ ?preis=$1 [L] Any ideas?

Comment: @CaroFiedler When did the RewriteRule come into play? You should have mentioned this in your question. Plus I knew I was right about the `&&` logical operator ;-)

Comment: @CaroFiedler remember I have put an else statement to prove whether or not the first three conditions are being met, if not it just uses a default. This need to be removed. Really not sure about the rewrite rule.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell if you don't give us an example of the `$_GET['preis']` value.

In your case I guess none of the `if` are being evaluated as true, also this might be easier:

```
$preis="";
if(isset($_GET['preis'])){
    $g_preis=$_GET['preis'];
    $parts=explode('-', $g_preis);
    $preis="WHERE preis >= $parts[0] and preis <= $parts[1]";
}else{
    echo "NO query for you!";
}
```

Comment: Yikes! `$_GET['preis']` directly in the query!

Comment: just changed what the OP was doing. Ofc the contents should be checked, or use mysqli_ functions.

Comment: Oh yes. Not worthy of a downvote but a comment.

Comment: Such an open SQL injection worth 10 downvotes.

Comment: If you use mysqli_ functions it's not a open anything... also I was just moving his code to make it shorter, didn't add any new functionality.

Comment: I noticed you didn't post a comment until questioned. So you downvote rather than advise? Stackoverflow may not be for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_GET['preis']) AND $_GET['preis']==="0-100-euro"){
$preis = "WHERE preis >= 0 and preis <= 100";
}
if (isset($_GET['preis']) AND $_GET['preis']==="100-200-euro"){
$preis = "WHERE preis >= 100 and preis <= 200";
}
if (isset($_GET['preis']) AND $_GET['preis']==="200-300-euro"){
$preis = "WHERE preis >= 200 and preis <= 300";
}
?>


$abfrage = "SELECT * FROM outfits ".$preis." LIMIT $start, $eintraege_pro_seite";
$ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage);
```

Comment: This will make no difference

Comment: @popnoodles agreed, can't see the benefit of this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you escape all string values to countermeasure sql injection attacks. Also the if jungle is going to make your code quite unmaintainable.

Have a look at this

```
$sPresis = (isset($_GET['preis'])) ? $_GET['preis'] : '';

$abfrage = 'SELECT * FROM outfits WHERE 1=1 ' . $this->buildWhereQuery($sPresis) .'LIMIT ' . implode(',', array($start, $eintraege_pro_seite));
$ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage);


function buildWhereQuery($sPresis){
    $sPresis = (string) $sPresis; // mysqli escape this as well

    switch($sPresis){
        case "0-100-euro":
            return 'AND preis >= 0 AND preis <= 100';

        case "100-200-euro":
            return 'AND preis >= 100 AND preis <= 200';

        case "200-300-euro":
            return 'AND preis >= 200 AND preis <= 300';
        default:
            return '';
    }
}
```